# How to have the apostrophes character in a password for a SQL connection string?

Tags: .net, string, connection-string

My connection string:

```
 "SQLConnectionString": "Server=112;Database=1;User ID=1;Password=''.KPQ`1U66zs*!dsasa2"
```

Those apostrophes cause an exception. How do I write this password into a connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Passwords inside double-quotes will accept single-quotes as-is; double-quotes must be doubled if they are inside double-quotes.

So the connection string `...;Password="a'b'c"` is valid, which would be written in C# as

```cs
var connectionString = @"...;Password=""a'b'c""";
```

To see the correct escaping, `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` can be useful:

```cs
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(yourStringWithoutPassword);
builder.Password = yourPassword;
Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString);
```

But that leaves the question of how to *escape* that value to put it in where-ever you're writing it.

Comment: I want to put it in a json file. And I use it, I call it with the function GetConnectionString(); i use .net